# Complex integral

Tags: cv.complex-variables, integration

We would like to compute (or bound) the following complex integral:

$$\int\limits_0^{\infty}\left|\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{its}}{e^s-\lambda}\,ds\right|\,dt$$

where $\lambda \notin S_{\alpha}$, $\omega >0$, $\alpha \in (\omega, \pi)$, and $S_{\alpha}:= \{z\in \mathbb{C}: |\arg{\lambda}|<\alpha \}.$

We think it should be at least bounded by $1/\left|\lambda\right|C'$ where $C'$ is some constant, the residue method has given us nothing.

Comment: Perhaps the inner improper integral diverges at $s=-\infty$ ?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  The problem was with the inner integral, not with the outer one. Besides, how do you know what the OP really had in mind? I am even confused by the meaning of the word "to bound": from above or from below?

Comment: @fedja:  I don't think I changed that aspect of the meaning in my edits.

Answer (score 1):

*Mathematica* is of the opinion that the inner integraL diverges when $t$ is real, and otherwise claims:

$$
\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{t \lambda^{i t} B_\lambda(1-i t,0)-t
   \left(\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)^{-i t} B_{\frac{1}{\lambda}}(i t+1,0)+i}{\lambda t},(\Re(\lambda)=1\lor \Re(\lambda)\leq
   0\lor \lambda\notin \mathbb{R})\land \Im(t)<0\land \Im(t)+1>0\right]
$$